# Internet Explorer And Interspire Shopping Cart Compatability Issues

Tags: html, css

My shopping cart renders perfectly on every other browser besides IE. I am losing customers and have looked everywhere to solve this issue. If anyone could help that would be awesome. Below are my css files. I am not sure what else you guys would need to help me out. Let me know.

```
* html #Logo h1 {
background : url(../../default/images/blue/Logo.gif) top left no-repeat;
}
* html .Left .TopSeller1, * html .Right .TopSeller1 {
margin-top : 0;
}
* html .Left .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .TopSellerNumber, * html .Right .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .TopSellerNumber {
background : url(../../default/images/blue/TopSellerNumber1Bg.gif) 0% 0% no-repeat;
margin : 0;
}
* html #Menu li a {
float : left;
}
* html .Left {
height : 490px;
}
* html .Right {
height : 490px;
}
* html .Content {
height : 500px;
}
* html .SelectGiftWrapMultiple {
height : 400px;
}
#SearchForm .Button {
vertical-align : bottom;
}
select, input {
font-size : 0.95em;
}
#Container {
width : 980px;
}
.ProductAddToCart dt div.Required, #CartEditProductFieldsForm dt div.Required {
margin-left : 0;
}
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
body {
font-family : "sans bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size : 1em;
height : 100%;
}
input, select {
font-size : 11px;
}
input {
padding : 1px;
}
p {
line-height : 1.3;
margin-bottom : 15px;
}
a {
font-weight : normal;
text-decoration : none;
}
h2, .TitleHeading {
font-size : 1.9em;
font-weight : bold;
margin : 6px 0 6px 0;
}
h3 {
font-size : 1.1em;
font-weight : bold;
margin-bottom : 6px;
}
h4 {
font-size : 1.1em;
margin-bottom : 4px;
}
img, img a {
border : 0;
}
ul, ol {
margin : 0 0 10px 30px;
}
li {
margin : 0;
margin-bottom : 2px;
padding : 0;
}
blockquote {
margin-left : 28px;
}
select option {
padding : 0 10px;
}
hr {
margin : 10px 0;
padding : 0;
background : #c7d7db;
height : 1px;
border : 0;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer dl, .VerticalFormContainer dl {
margin : 0;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer dt img {
vertical-align : middle;
float : left;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer dt .fieldLabel {
float : left;
padding-top : 4px;
padding-left : 4px;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer dt {
width : 160px;
float : left;
clear : left;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer dd.ProductField {
height : 20px;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer dd {
padding-top : 4px;
margin-left : 170px;
}
.NarrowFormContainer dt {
width : 110px;
}
.NarrowFormContainer dd {
margin-left : 120px;
}
.HorizontalFormContainer p.Submit {
margin-left : 170px;
}
.NarrowFormContainer p.Submit {
margin-left : 120px;
}
.VerticalFormContainer dt {
margin-bottom : 6px;
}
.VerticalFormContainer dd {
margin-bottom : 6px;
margin-left : 10px;
}
#Container {
width : 983px;
margin : 0 auto;
background : #fff;
}
#TopMenu {
background : #eaeaea none repeat scroll 0 0;
height : 25px;
padding : 0;
}
#TopMenu ul {
float : right;
margin : 1px 10px 0 0;
padding : 0;
}
#TopMenu li {
list-style : none;
float : left;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
#TopMenu li.First a {
border-left : 0;
}
#TopMenu li a, #TopMenu li div {
display : inline;
text-decoration : none;
font-size : 0.60em;
padding : 0 10px 0 10px;
margin : 8px 0 0 0;
}
#TopMenu li div a {
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
display : inline;
font-size : 1em;
}
#TopMenu li a:hover {
text-decoration : none;
}
#Menu {
clear : both;
margin : 0 0 10px;
padding : 0;
height : 30px;
background : transparent url('../../default/images/blue/menu-bg.jpg') repeat-x;
}
#Menu ul {
margin : 5em 0;
padding : 0;
}
#Menu li {
float : none;
position : relative;
list-style : none;
margin : 50px;
padding : 0;
}
#Menu li.First a {
background-image : none;
}
#Menu li a {
display : inline;
float : left;
font-size : 15px;
font-weight : bolder;
text-align : center;
text-decoration : none;
padding : 6px 35px 3px 10px;
height : 20px;
}
#Menu li a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
#Menu li ul {
width : auto;
position : absolute;
clear : left;
top : 5px;
left : 0;
display : none;
text-align : left;
font-size : 1.1em;
background : transparent;
z-index : 1;
}
#Menu li ul li {
clear : both;
text-align : left;
}
#Menu li ul li a {
padding : 3px 10px 3px 10px;
font-size : 1.33em;
text-align : left;
margin : 0;
width : 300px;
height : auto;
}
#Menu li ul li a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
#Menu li:hover a, #Menu li.over a {
text-decoration : none;
}
#Menu li ul li a, #Menu li.over li a {
text-decoration : none !important ;
}
#Menu li:hover ul, #Menu li.over ul {
display : inline;
}
* html #Menu ul li {
float : left;
height : 1%;
}
* html #Menu ul li a {
height : 1%;
}
#Outer {
margin-top : 0;
clear : both;
}
#Wrapper {
clear : both;
}
#Header {
height : 57px;
clear : both;
margin : 0 0 1px 0;
padding-bottom : 12px;
}
#Logo {
float : left;
width : 230px;
margin-left : 172px;
margin-top : 10px;
}
#Logo h1 {
font-size : 2.4em;
font-weight : normal;
padding-left : 64px;
height : 45px;
margin-top : 10px;
}
#Logo h1 a {
text-decoration : none;
}
#SearchForm {
padding-top : 20px;
float : right;
margin-right : 10px;
}
#SearchForm label {
font-weight : bold;
}
#SearchForm input.Textbox {
width : 139px;
border : #e5e6ea solid 1px;
background : #fff;
font-size : 0.9em;
padding : 2px;
}
#SearchForm .Button {
width : 27px;
height : 21px;
padding : 0;
margin-top : -4px;
vertical-align : middle;
margin-left : -5px;
}
#SearchForm p {
text-align : right;
margin : 0 0 0 45px;
font-size : 0.9em;
}
#SearchForm a {
text-decoration : none;
}
.Left {
float : left;
min-height : 500px;
width : 160px;
font-size : 1em;
margin-right : 5px;
}
.Left h2 {
font-size : 22px;
margin : 20px 15px 10px;
width : 140px;
font-family : "arial black", Times, serif;
color : #b72f0b;
font-weight : bolder;
}
.Left a {
color : #000;
padding-left : 8px;
font-size : 15px;
font-weight : bold;
}
.Left li a:hover {
background-color : #ffffff;
}
.Left .BlockContent {
margin : 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.Left ul {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
.Left li {
clear : both;
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 3px 0;
}
.Left .BlockContent {
margin : 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.Left li {
border-bottom : 10px solid #ffffff;
}
.Left li a {
text-decoration : none;
}
.Left li a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li ul {
border-top : 1px solid #ef810a;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li.LastChild {
border-bottom : 0 !important ;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li {
padding : 7px 0 0 0;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li ul {
padding-left : 15px;
}
.Content {
float : left;
width : 576px;
min-height : 500px;
margin : 0;
padding : 0 5px 0;
font-size : 0.95em;
font-weight : bold;
}
.Content .Block {
clear : both;
}
.Block {
margin-top : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.Content h2, .TitleHeading {
font-size : 24px;
font-weight : bold;
color : #000;
margin : 10px 0;
text-align : center;
border-bottom : 1px solid #c7c7c7;
padding-bottom : 5px;
font-family : "hobo std", Times, serif;
}
.Content a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
.Content.Wide {
width : 785px;
}
.Content.Widest {
width : 955px;
}
.Right {
float : right;
min-height : 500px;
width : 218px;
font-size : 0.85em;
padding-bottom : 10px;
margin-left : 4px;
margin-right : 10px;
}
.Right h2 {
font-size : 25px;
margin : 5px 10px 8px;
width : 140px;
font-family : "Comic Sans MS", Times, serif;
color : #b72f0b;
font-weight : bolder;
}
.Right a {
color : #000;
}
.Right li a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
.Right .BlockContent {
margin : 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.Right ul {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
.Right li {
clear : both;
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 3px 0;
}
.Right .BlockContent {
margin : 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.Right li {
border-bottom : 1px solid #c5dde9;
text-align : center;
}
.Right li a {
text-decoration : none;
}
.Right li a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
#Footer {
clear : both;
font-size : 0.85em;
text-align : center;
margin : -25px 0 0 0;
padding : 5px 0 0 0;
}
#Footer ul {
list-style : none;
margin : 0 0 30px 115px;
padding : 0;
}
#Footer li {
float : left;
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
#Footer li a {
text-decoration : none;
padding : 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.NewsletterSubscription {
clear : both;
}
.NewsletterSubscription label {
clear : both;
float : left;
}
.NewsletterSubscription input {
width : 129px;
font-size : 0.9em;
padding : 3px;
margin-bottom : 5px;
}
.NewsletterSubscription .Button {
width : 68px;
height : 20px;
border : 0;
margin-top : 6px;
vertical-align : middle;
}
.ProductList {
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
.Content .ProductList li {
list-style : none;
float : left;
width : 122px;
font-size : 0.95em;
margin : 2px;
padding : 8px;
overflow : hidden;
min-height : 17em;
text-align : center;
}
.ProductList a {
text-decoration : none;
}
.ProductList .ProductImage {
margin : 0 0 5px 0;
display : table-cell;
width : 120px;
height : 120px;
text-align : center;
overflow : hidden;
vertical-align : middle;
}
.ProductList .ProductImage img {
vertical-align : middle;
}
.ProductList p {
margin : 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
.ProductList strong, .ProductList strong a {
color : #ff0078;
}
.ProductPrice, .ProductList em {
font-style : normal;
font-weight : bold;
font-size : 1.4em;
color : #000000;
}
.ProductList .Rating {
font-size : 0.9em;
font-weight : bold;
}
.ProductList .Rating img {
height : 12px;
margin-top : 3px;
}
.ProductList li .ProductCompareButton {
margin-top : 3px;
text-align : center;
}
.Left .ProductList .ProductImage, .Right .ProductList .ProductImage {
display : block;
}
.Left .ProductList li, .Right .ProductList li {
clear : both;
width : 140px;
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
margin-top : 5px;
padding : 3px 0 1px 0;
color : #000000;
}
.Right .SideCart p {
color : #000000;
}
.Left .TopSellers li .TopSellerNumber, .Right .TopSellers li .TopSellerNumber {
float : left;
width : 20px;
font-size : 1.2em;
padding : 6px 0 3px 6px;
}
.Left .TopSellers .ProductDetails, .Right .TopSellers .ProductDetails {
margin-left : 24px;
width : 110px;
padding : 3px 0 3px 0;
}
.Left .TopSellers li.TopSeller1, .Right .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 {
clear : both;
float : left;
width : 128px;
margin : 10px 0 5px 0;
padding : 5px;
overflow : visible;
display : inline;
}
.Left .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 img, .Right .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 img {
text-align : center;
overflow : hidden;
max-width : 130px;
}
.Left .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .TopSellerNumber, .Right .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .TopSellerNumber {
width : 44px;
height : 34px;
font-size : 2em;
padding : 7px 0 6px 0;
margin : -20px 0 0 0;
text-align : center;
display : block;
}
.Left .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .ProductDetails, .Right .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .ProductDetails {
margin-left : 0;
}
.Left .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .ProductImage, .Right .TopSellers li.TopSeller1 .ProductImage {
width : 130px;
display : inline;
text-align : center;
overflow : hidden;
}
.Content .TopSellers li .TopSellerNumber {
display : none;
}
.Breadcrumb ul, .Breadcrumb li {
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
.Breadcrumb {
font-size : 0.9em;
padding-bottom : 4px;
border-bottom : 1px solid #DCDFE2;
}
.Breadcrumb li {
padding-left : 6px;
display : inline;
}
.Breadcrumb li a {
padding-right : 0;
background : url('../../default/images/BreadcrumbSep.gif') no-repeat right;
}
.FindByCategory ul, .FindByCategory li {
list-style : none;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.FindByCategory li {
padding-left : 12px;
background : url('../../default/images/BreadcrumbSep.gif') no-repeat 3px 5px;
padding-right : 8px;
display : inline;
}
.Meta {
color : #444;
font-size : 0.93em;
}
.Left .FeedLink, .Right .FeedLink {
padding-right : 5px;
}
.Content .FeedLink {
margin-top : 4px;
}
.FloatRight {
float : right;
}
.FloatLeft {
float : left;
}
.ClearRight {
clear : right;
}
.ClearLeft {
clear : left;
}
.SortBox {
font-size : 0.95em;
color : #444;
}
.CompareButton {
clear : both;
text-align : right;
margin-top : 12px;
padding : 4px;
}
.Clear {
clear : both;
}
.Field45 {
width : 45px;
}
.Field100 {
width : 100px;
}
.Field150 {
width : 150px;
}
.Field200 {
width : 200px;
}
.Field250 {
width : 250px;
}
.Field300 {
width : 300px;
}
.Field350 {
width : 350px;
}
.Field400 {
width : 400px;
}
.MB10 {
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.MT0 {
margin-top : 0;
}
.LH140 {
line-height : 140%;
}
.PLRB5 {
padding : 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
.PLR10 {
padding : 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.PL20 {
padding : 0 0 0 20px;
}
.PL40 {
padding : 0 0 0 40px;
}
.ML20 {
margin : 0 0 0 20px;
}
.MT10 {
margin-top : 10px;
}
.PL10 {
padding-left : 10px;
}
.PB2 {
padding-bottom : 2px;
}
.NoMarginBottom {
margin-bottom : 0;
}
.Required {
color : red;
font-weight : bold;
visibility : visible;
}
.InfoMessage {
padding : 8px 6px 8px 28px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.SuccessMessage {
padding : 8px 6px 8px 28px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.ErrorMessage {
padding : 8px 6px 8px 28px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.CreateAccount {
float : left;
width : 335px;
border-right : 1px solid #ccc;
padding-right : 20px;
}
.AccountLogin {
float : left;
padding-left : 20px;
width : 335px;
}
ul.ShippingAddressList, ul.ShippingAddressList li {
list-style : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
ul.ShippingAddressList li {
width : 30%;
float : left;
margin-right : 10px;
margin-bottom : 20px;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails .ProductThumb {
float : left;
width : 190px;
text-align : center;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails .ProductMain {
width : 320px;
float : left;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails dl {
font-size : 0.90em;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails dt {
font-weight : bold;
width : 80px;
clear : left;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails dd {
margin-left : 90px;
}
.Right hr {
margin : 5px 0 0;
}
.Content h3 {
font-size : 24px;
font-weight : bold;
color : #000;
margin-bottom : 5px;
}
.ComparisonCheckbox {
float : left;
}
.SideRecentlyViewed .CompareButton {
margin : 10px 0 0 0;
padding : 0;
}
.SideRecentlyViewed .ProductList li {
margin-left : 0;
}
.SideRecentlyViewed .ProductDetails {
margin-left : 20px;
}
.ComparisonTable {
width : 100%;
}
.ComparisonTable td {
vertical-align : top;
font-size : 11px;
}
.CompareFieldName {
width : 95px;
padding : 8px 10px 8px 15px;
}
.CompareFieldTop {
padding : 5px;
text-align : center;
}
.CompareFieldTop a {
text-decoration : none;
font-size : 10px;
}
.CompareFieldTop a:hover {
text-decoration : underline;
}
.CompareLeft {
padding : 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.CompareCenter {
text-align : center;
padding : 5px;
}
.CompareRating {
text-align : center;
padding-top : 8px;
vertical-align : middle;
}
.CompareProductOption {
margin-left : 20px;
padding-left : 5px;
}
.Availability {
color : gray;
}
.LittleNote {
color : gray;
font-size : 0.85em;
}
.ViewCartLink {
padding-left : 30px;
padding-top : 4px;
padding-bottom : 8px;
}
table.General, table.CartContents, table.General {
width : 100%;
margin : 10px 0;
}
table.General thead tr th, table.CartContents thead tr th {
padding : 6px 10px;
text-align : left;
}
table.General tbody td, table.CartContents tbody td {
padding : 6px 10px;
vertical-align : top;
}
table.General tbody tr.First td {
border-top : 0;
}
.CartContents tbody td, .CartContents tfoot td {
border-bottom : 0;
}
.CartContents .ProductName a {
font-weight : bold;
}
.ProceedToCheckout {
text-align : right;
}
.Content .ProceedToCheckout {
width : 200px;
float : right;
}
.ProceedToCheckout a {
padding-top : 5px;
}
.MiniCart .SubTotal {
text-align : center;
font-size : 115%;
color : #075899;
}
.MiniCart .CartProductOptionList {
display : block;
}
.JustAddedProduct {
width : 128px;
overflow : hidden;
margin : auto;
text-align : center;
padding : 5px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.JustAddedProduct strong, .JustAddedProduct a {
font-weight : bold;
font-size : 1.02em;
display : block;
margin-bottom : 3px;
}
.CategoryPagination .PagingList, .CategoryPagination .PagingList li {
list-style : none;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.CategoryPagination {
padding : 5px;
text-align : center;
}
.CategoryPagination .PagingList li {
display : inline;
padding : 0 5px;
}
.QuickSearch {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
text-align : left;
border-collapse : collapse;
background : #fff;
border : #BFBFBF solid 1px;
}
.QuickSearchTitle td, .QuickSearchAllResults td {
font-weight : bold;
padding : 4px;
font-size : 11px;
}
.QuickSearchResult td {
font-size : 11px;
padding : 8px;
cursor : pointer;
}
.QuickSearchResultImage {
margin-left : 4px;
margin-right : 10px;
text-align : center;
}
.QuickSearchResultNoImage {
padding-top : 10px;
color : #777;
}
.QuickSearchResultName {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
padding-bottom : 5px;
}
.QuickSearchResultName a {
font-weight : bold;
text-decoration : none;
}
.QuickSearchResult .Price {
font-size : 11px;
}
.QuickSearchHover td {
background : #E8F4F8;
}
.QuickSearchHover a {
text-decoration : underline;
font-weight : bold;
}
.QuickSearchAllResults td {
text-align : right;
height : 25px;
}
.QuickSearchAllResults a {
text-decoration : underline;
}
.QuickSearchAllResults a:active, .QuickSearchAllResults a {
outline : none;
}
.BrandCloud .smallest {
font-size : 12px;
}
.BrandCloud .small {
font-size : 15px;
}
.BrandCloud .medium {
font-size : 18px;
}
.BrandCloud .large {
font-size : 20px;
}
.BrandCloud .largest {
font-size : 26px;
}
.BrandCloud a {
padding-right : 5px;
}
.DownloadExpires {
padding-top : 3px;
font-style : italic;
color : gray;
}
.DownloadExpiresToday {
color : red;
}
.CheckoutRedeemCoupon h4 {
margin-top : 0;
}
.CheckoutRedeemCoupon p {
margin-top : 10px;
margin-bottom : 0;
}
.BillingDetails {
float : left;
width : 48%;
margin-right : 10px;
margin-bottom : 15px;
}
.ShippingDetails {
float : left;
width : 48%;
margin-bottom : 15px;
}
.ProductDetailsGrid dt {
width : 140px;
margin-bottom : 6px;
float : left;
font-weight : bold;
}
.ProductDetailsGrid dd {
margin-left : 145px;
margin-bottom : 6px;
}
.SubCategoryList {
padding : 4px;
}
.SubCategoryList ul, .SubCategoryList li {
list-style : none;
margin-left : 0;
}
.SubCategoryList li {
margin-bottom : 4px;
padding-left : 25px;
background : url('../../default/images/SubCategory.gif') no-repeat 3px 1px;
width : 250px;
float : left;
}
.SearchTips .Examples {
padding : 8px;
border : #aaa solid 1px;
color : #555;
margin-left : 30px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails .ProductThumb p {
margin-top : 10px;
font-size : 0.9em;
}
.ProductReviewList {
clear : both;
}
.SortBox select {
font-size : 0.9em;
}
.SortBox option {
color : #444;
}
.YourAccount li {
margin-bottom : 8px;
}
.SoldOut {
color : #999;
}
.RemoveFromWishlistForm {
margin : 5px;
}
.ShippingProviderList {
list-style : none;
}
small {
font-size : 11px;
color : gray;
}
.HowToPay {
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.ProductList em, .ProductList .Rating {
display : block;
}
.GoogleCheckout p, .PayPalExpressCheckout p, .AlternativeCheckout p {
margin : 0;
font-size : 90%;
}
.GoogleCheckout, .PayPalExpressCheckout, .AlternativeCheckout {
text-align : center;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.KeepShopping {
width : 180px;
clear : both;
text-align : right;
}
#TopMenu li.Flag {
float : right;
}
#TopMenu li.Flag div {
border : 0;
}
#TopMenu li.Flag img {
margin : 3px;
}
#TopMenu li.Flag img.Last {
margin-right : 0;
}
#TopMenu li.Flag img.Selected {
border : #ffffaa solid 2px;
margin : 1px 3px;
}
.CurrencyList dl {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
.CurrencyList dd {
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
border : #EDECEC solid 1px;
background-color : #F9F9F9;
clear : both;
}
.CurrencyList a {
padding : 0 3px 0 5px;
display : block;
line-height : 1.8;
text-decoration : none;
font-size : 11px;
}
.CurrencyList a.Sel {
background-color : #FFFFAA;
}
.CurrencyList a:hover .Text {
text-decoration : underline;
}
.CurrencyList a .Flag {
margin-top : 4px;
display : block;
float : left;
width : 24px;
padding-right : 2px;
vertical-align : middle;
}
.CurrencyList a .Text {
display : block;
padding-left : 24px;
}
.PrimaryProductDetails .YouSave {
font-weight : bold;
margin-top : 3px;
display : block;
}
.EstimateShipping {
margin-top : 4px;
margin-bottom : 4px;
font-weight : normal;
width : 320px;
padding : 7px;
float : right;
}
.EstimateShipping dt {
width : 100px;
float : left;
margin-bottom : 8px;
clear : left;
}
.EstimateShipping dd {
margin-bottom : 8px;
font-weight : normal;
text-align : left;
margin-left : 114px;
}
.EstimateShipping p.Submit {
margin-top : 10px;
margin-bottom : 3px;
}
.EstimateShipping label {
display : block;
margin-bottom : 5px;
}
.EstimatedShippingMethods {
text-align : left;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate ie.css file with ISC